# in perl, how do we detect a segmentation fault in an external command

Tags: perl

Following is C code that is destined to crash:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *p = NULL;
    printf("Value at P: %c\n", *p);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run it (RH4 machine with gcc 4.5.2), it predictably gives a segmentation fault:

```
%  ./a.out
Segmentation fault

%  echo $status
139
```

If I run it with Perl v5.8.5, this happens:

```
%  perl -e 'system("./a.out") and die "Status: $?"'
Status: 11 at -e line 1.
```

The [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) documentation for `$?` says that

> Thus, the exit value of the subprocess is really `($?>> 8 )`, and `$? &
>   127` gives which signal, if any, the process died from, and `$? & 128`
>   reports whether there was a core dump.

`11 >> 8` is `0`, and `11 & 127` is `11`.

Why the different exit statuses? If we cannot depend on the exit status, what should be the way to detect segmentation fault in an external command?

Comment: How is `$status` set?

Comment: It looks like you're actually getting the signal your process died from : 11 is segmentation fault, and `139 & 127 = 11`

Comment: I just tried it with Cygwin (perl v 5.14.2) and it gave me : `Status: 139 at -e line 1.`

Comment: Note that `139 & 127` is equivalent to `11 & 127`. Any number `n` larger than 127 is going to alias to `n % 128`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Reading the documentation for `system` might answer your question:

```
system('a.out');

if ($? == -1) {
    print "failed to execute: $!\n";
}
elsif ($? & 127) {
    printf "child died with signal %d, %s coredump\n",
        ($? & 127),  ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without';
}
else {
    printf "child exited with value %d\n", $? >> 8;
}
```

Output:

```
child died with signal 11, without coredump
```

The shell just encodes the signal in the status in a different way: 139 - 128 = 11. For example, `man bash` says:

> The  return  value  of a simple command is its exit status, or 128+n if the command is terminated by signal n.

Comment: @Unos, Signal numbers start at 1 and can go up to 127. Exit codes over 128 from the shell are ambiguous since it mashes the "killed by signal" and "exited with error" numbers together. e.g. is `139` a kill by SEGFAULT or `exit(139)`? Can't tell from the shell, but can tell from Perl.

Comment: ok, so if i understand correctly, shell sees a signal for seg-fault, `00001011`, and sets the high bit, so the status becomes `10001011`, or 139. Perl decodes it correctly and sets `$?` to 11.

Answer (score 3):

The OS always sees the same thing... what is returned by the wait(2) family of functions. system(3), et. all, call wait(2). How it peculates up you is what is causing the differences. The shell and the programs do different things and report different ways. Having to shift right 8 to get the most common exit status would be very annoying in shell programs and confuse less tech savvy users.

While the very first UNIX systems I used (genuine Unix) had the same returns I have always wondered if pre-release versions were different and returning the signal and core/dump were a later addition.

My preferred reporting of exit status tends to have the computer split my bits for me.

```
   my $x = $?;   #save status
   print( "Exit status: %d.%d%s\n",
              $x>>8, $x&127, ($x&128)?"*":"" );
```